# WIndows 7 command line input

Tags: windows-7, batch

I have a drivers folder on my file server. I am writing a command line script that will prompt the user to enter a computer model number. the script will then use that input to copy over the correct folder.

This is my script

```
set /p model="Enter Model Number"

mkdir c:\j2Global\%model%

xcopy /s /e /y "\\j2hqfil01\software\01_ALL DRIVERS\Dell\Desktops\%model%" "C:\j2Global\%model%\"

pause
```

what im wondering is if its possible to prepend text to input.

the drivers folders are named Optiplex 9010 or Latitude E5440 for example so currently the user has to type out Optiplex or Latitude.

Is there a way to change the folder path so that if the user enters 9010 it will grab the Optiplex 9010 folder?

I guess that im looking for is to change the folder path "\j2hqfil01\software\01_ALL DRIVERS\Dell\Desktops\%model%" to something like "\j2hqfil01\software\01_ALL DRIVERS\Dell\Desktops*%model%"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you only have 2 possible choices, the easiest way is to simply verify if a folder exists and try that for both situations. if it does, it copies the files. This is the script:

```
set /p model="Enter model number"
set "model1=OptiPlex %model%"
set "model2=Latitude %model%"

if exists "\\j2hqfil01\software\01_ALL DRIVERS\Dell\Desktops\%model1%" (
     :: enter commands for OptiPlex below this line

)

if exists "\\j2hqfil01\software\01_ALL DRIVERS\Dell\Desktops\%model2%" (
     :: enter commands for Latitude below this line

)
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm wondering is if its possible to prepend text to input.

Here's an example of prepending text onto a variable:

```
set /p model="Enter Model Number"
set model=OptiPlex %model%
```

User inputs `9010`, it prepends "Optiplex " to it and assigns the new value (back) to 'model', so in the end "model" now has a value of `OptiPlex 9010`.

How you use that to pick which folder you want is a different story, and should really be it's own separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the /I argument if you will use if(s) to make it case in-sensitive.

I would use the FINDSTR regex if I was to check if a sub-string is part of a string. With regular expressions, you can make a set of rules.

Create array with Model + Number

If a value or some values are part of the array, it would pass.

> Example Code :
>
> :start
>
> cls
>
> set /p model = "Enter your model"
>
> set name1=Optiplex
>
> set name2=Latitude
>
> set number1=9010
>
> set number2=E5440
>
> ECHO %name1% %number1%
>
> ECHO %name2% %number2%
>
> set /p model1=%name1% %number1%
>
> set /p model2=%name2% %number2%
>
> :label
>
> rem Add code to manage multiple devices more easily like a FOR LOOP to load the 20
>
> rem variables one by one in dummy variables.
>
> :loop
>
> IF %model%==%model1%|%name1%|%number1% (
>
> ECHO You choose %model1%!
>
> goto :path
>
> )
>
> IF %model%==%model2%|%name2%|%number2% (
>
> ECHO You choose %model2%!
>
> goto :path
>
> ) ELSE (
>
> ECHO Wrong Command !
>
> goto :start )
>
> :path
>
> rem Input your XCOPY script here !